# How can I add a column to a file that is matched to another column?

Tags: awk

How can I match the first column from file1 according to the numbers in the second column to the file 2?

#### File *file1*

```
k002  25
k004  54
k003  23
```

#### File *file2*

```
25 h
23 j
54 hg
```

#### Desired output

```
k002 25 h
k003 23 j
k004 54 hg
```

I have no idea how to do that, and I did not find similar questions.

```
awk 'matching {print ... $1, $2}' file1 file2 > file_des
```

Comment: Please [edit] the tags on your question to tell us which shell you're using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could perhaps do something like this:

```c
awk 'NR == FNR { x[$2]=$1; next} { print x[$1], $0 }' file1 file2
```

Where:

- `FNR`: The input record number in the current input file.
- `NR` : The total number of input records seen so far.

Note that this will read entire `file1` into memory.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't care about preserving original file order you can use `join`:

```
# sort the first file:
sort -k2 file1 > nfile1

# Sort the second file:
sort file2 > nfile2

join -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1,1.2,2.2 nfile1 nfile2 > joined_file
```

Or as suggested by @Ed Morton, if you use `bash` or any other shell that support process sobstitution, you can avoid creating temporary files in this way:

```
join -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1,1.2,2.2 <(sort -k2 file1) <(sort file2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

`awk 'NR==FNR{ar[$2]=$0;next}($1 in ar){print ar[$1],$2}' file1 file2`

In this command `NR==FNR` ensures that `{ar[$2]=$0;next}` will work for first file only because after reading first file `FNR` would be set to zero.
In expression `{ar[$2]=$0;next}` an array `ar` indexed on `$2` is created and with `next` no further actions are taken.

The expression `($1 in ar)` sees if `$1` (first field of second file) is present in *indices* of array `ar`. If present, then this prints `ar` and second field of second file by this statement `{print ar[$1],$2}`.

`($1 in ar)` is important because this means whether $1 of second file matches *indices* of `ar`. And `ar` is indexed on $2 of first file. So this checks if `$1` of second file matches `$2` of first file.